# KendoUI Line Graph for Angular not displaying X Axis

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, linechart

I want to use KendoUI Line Graph for Angular which is not displaying X Axis Label. I tried editing the existing example where the code is as follows:

```
 k-series="[
                             { field: 'nuclear', name: 'Nuclear electricity' },
                             { field: 'hydro', name: 'Hydro electricity' },
                             { field: 'wind', name: 'Wind electricity' }
                         ]
```

I tries changing the code as shown in some other angular chart example by KendoUI as

`k-series="[{ xField: 'price', yField: 'performance' }]"
                 k-x-axis="{
                                max: 1000,
                                labels: { format: '${0}' },
                                title: { text: 'Price' }
                             }"
                 k-y-axis="{
                                min: 80,
                                labels: { format: '{0}%' },
                                title: { text: 'Performance Ratio' }`

But it seems if your chart type is line, it doesn't recognizes k-x-axis and k-y-axis .

`k-series-defaults="{ type: 'line'}"`

Please provide help as how I can show x-axis values:
Link to their Angular Line Chart is as follows:

To see the information about this chart, please see 
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/line-charts/angular 
For Editing : http://dojo.telerik.com/iVOxo

Answer (score 0):

Scatter charts, such as `scatterLine` use the axes configured in `xAxis` and `yAxis`. Arrays are accepted when defining multiple axes.

In your example the series type is set to `line`. This series type uses the `categoryAxis` and `valueAxis`. Therefore the axis configuration, as it is, will be ignored.

You should remove the `field: '...'` bindings and change the series type to `scatterLine`

`k-series-defaults="{ type: 'scatterLine'}"`

I hope this helps.